# Sending emails with ASP.NET Membership Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I currently have credentials in my Web.Config for sending password reset emails using the Membership in asp.net

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="password@*****.com">
        <network host="mail.*****.com" password="*****"
                 userName="password@*****.com" enableSsl="false"/>
      </smtp>

    </mailSettings>

  </system.net>
```

This works great for the password reset.

Now when trying to send a custom email using the same credentials I always receive error "Failure to send mail."

```
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("me@gmail.com"));
            mailMessage.Subject = "mailSubject";
            mailMessage.Body = "mailBody";

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the SmtpClient uses the webconfig credentials. You do this by setting the UseDefaultCredentials property to false like:

```
     SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
     smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
```

Comment: It does use default credentials because the inner exception is InnerException = {"The remote name could not be resolved: 'mail.******.com'"}. But I have set to false and still have the same issue.

Comment: That is odd, that implies an address/port/protocol issue.

Comment: Usually you have to specify the port you're using (normally port 25).  Use the `smtpClient.Port` property to set this.

Comment: @AlecC I must have been missing something in web.config.  I opened up the ASP.NET Configuration tool, went to configure SMTP settings, and everything was pre-filled out. I just pushed save and it said made changes to web.config. Works now